# Giving data to gameObjects without referencing self

Tags: unity, c#

Before I start on the problem, I would like to clarify a bit on the design of the system that I have issue with.

I have made a `StatusEffectController` and a `StatusEffectBaseClass` which uses the `IStatusEffect` interface. I make derived classes of `StatusEffectBaseClass` and add them as components to items that apply that status effect.

There is another script `WeaponMaster` which is a baseclass that contains a **List of "IStatusEffect`. On starting, it finds the status effects *(which are on the same game object as the script itself)*

When the weapon fires, it instantiates a projectile that contains a reference to the status effects of the weapon. This projectile, upon colliding with an object that has `StatusEffectController`, runs a function inside the `StatusEffectController` that accepts `IStatusEffect`. The function stores the `IStatusEffect` in its own list and runs the effects stored in the `StatusEffectBaseClass` 's derived class script.

---

The problem is, when the Projectile script gives the `StatusEffectController` its status effects, it gives them a reference to the one inside the weapon *(the original script that is a component on the weapon)*.

As I wrote this summary, I got a hint that I should Instantiate a new derivation of `StatusEffectBaseClass` ON the object I want to be affected and have the `StatusEffectController` reference that one instead of the one on the weapon.

Would that be a proper solution to the problem?

The following are portions of my scripts for:

WeaponMaster.cs:

```
public List<IStatusEffect> statusEffects = new List<IStatusEffect> ();

public GameObject projectile; // Irrelevant to this topic, it was just in the way.

float cooldown;

public void OnStart (){ // This is not called by itself, a derived class calls it instead.
    statusEffects.AddRange (gameObject.GetComponents<IStatusEffect> ());
    Debug.Log ("Got " + statusEffects.Count + " status effects on this weapon.");
}
```

ProjectileScript.cs:

```
public List<IStatusEffect> statusEffects;

//////////////////////////////////////
//IRRELEVANT STUFF HERE.
//////////////////////////////////////

    if(col.gameObject.GetComponent<StatusEffectController> () != null){//Deal status effects if the victim can process it. I should add a check to ignore this if the projectile has no status effects.
        StatusEffectController fX = col.gameObject.GetComponent<StatusEffectController> ();

        for(int i = 0; i < statusEffects.Count; i++){
            fX.ActivateEffect (statusEffects[i]);
        }
    }

    Die ();
}
```

StatusEffectController.cs:

```
//Gameobjects without this can not simulate status effects, but they may carry them.
//Weapons are an example, they can carry a status effect on them to apply to its victims but it can't be affected by it.

public List<IStatusEffect> activeEffects = new List<IStatusEffect>(); //Relevant.
public UnitStatum unit;


void Start () {
    unit = gameObject.GetComponent<UnitStatum> ();
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    if(activeEffects.Count > 0)
        UpdateEffects ();

}

public void ActivateEffect(IStatusEffect effect){ //Relevant.
    activeEffects.Add (effect);

    for(int i = 0; i < activeEffects.Count; i++){
        if(activeEffects[i] == effect){
            Debug.Log ("Status effects applied!");
            activeEffects [i].master = this.GetComponent<StatusEffectController> ();
            activeEffects [i].order = i;
            activeEffects [i].Activate ();
        }
    }
}

void UpdateEffects(){
    //Run down effect timers, check for expired effects and remove them.
    for(int i = 0; i < activeEffects.Count; i++){

        activeEffects [i].duration -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (activeEffects [i].duration <= 0){
            EndEffect (i);
        }
    }
}

public void EndEffect(int order){ //Relevant.
    //Remove the effect.
    activeEffects[order].Deactivate();
    activeEffects.RemoveAt (order);
    //Bring down the order of items that come after the removed object.
    for(int j = 0; j < activeEffects.Count - order;j++){
        activeEffects [order + j].order--;
    }

}
}
```

---

I have used @DMGregory 's method and got the system working. But I have encountered a couple of problems now.

First, the component that gets added is brand new and doesn't copy any modified variables in the weapon(I have tried a method to set all variables by code but it doesn't work as expected.

Second, I have replaced the `List<>` with a `Dictionary<>` to allow ease of organization/detection of existing effects. But I get a *"Collection was modified"* warning everytime I run a `foreach` loop through the `Dictionary<>` while another status effect is being applied.

Here is the latest `StatusEffectController` script:

```
public UnitStatum unit;

//Gameobjects without this can not simulate status effects, but they may carry them.
//Weapons are an example, they can carry a status effect on them to apply to its victims but it can't be affected by it.

Dictionary<string, IStatusEffect> activeEffects = new Dictionary<string, IStatusEffect>();


void Start () {
    unit = gameObject.GetComponent<UnitStatum> ();
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    if (activeEffects.Count > 0)
        UpdateEffects ();
}

public void AddEffect(IStatusEffect effect){
    Type typus = effect.GetType ();

    if (activeEffects.ContainsKey (effect._name)){
        if (activeEffects [effect._name]._stackable) {
            activeEffects [effect._name]._stack++;
        }
    } else {
        gameObject.AddComponent (typus);

        activeEffects.Add (effect._name, DuplicateEffect (effect, typus));
        activeEffects [effect._name].Activate ();
    }
}

void UpdateEffects(){
    //Run down effect timers, check for expired effects and remove them.
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IStatusEffect> effect in activeEffects){
        effect.Value._duration -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(effect.Value._duration <= 0){
            if (effect.Value._expireType == "Kill")
                EndEffect (effect.Value._name);
            else if (effect.Value._expireType == "Decay") {
                effect.Value._stack--;
                effect.Value._activeDuration = effect.Value._duration;
            }
        }
    }
}

IStatusEffect DuplicateEffect(IStatusEffect effect, Type ofType){
    IStatusEffect duplicant = (IStatusEffect)gameObject.GetComponent (ofType);

    duplicant.master = gameObject.GetComponent<StatusEffectController> ();
    duplicant._name = effect._name;
    duplicant._description = effect._description;
    duplicant._duration = effect._duration;
    duplicant._activeDuration = effect._activeDuration;
    duplicant._delay = effect._delay;
    duplicant._tickRate = effect._tickRate;
    duplicant._power = effect._power;
    duplicant._range = effect._range;
    duplicant._affects = effect._affects;
    duplicant._type = effect._type;
    duplicant._expireType = effect._expireType;
    duplicant._stack = effect._stack;
    duplicant._maxStack = effect._maxStack;
    duplicant._dispellable = effect._dispellable;
    duplicant._refreshable = effect._refreshable;
    duplicant._stackable = effect._stackable;

    return duplicant;
}

public void EndEffect(string effectName){
    //End the effect.

    activeEffects [effectName].Deactivate ();
    activeEffects.Remove (effectName);
}
}
```

In the `DuplicateEffect` function, using a `Debug.Log()` returns the correctly applied values, but looking at them in the inspector shows the default initialized values.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: `The problem is, when the Projectile script gives the "StatusEffectController" its status effects, it gives them a reference to the one inside the weapon (the original script that is a component on the weapon).` Why is this a problem? I mean, I wouldn't design the system that way, but since you *have*, this sentence only explains what your system is doing, not why that's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have up to three different jobs these IStatusEffect components may be serving:

- Marking a weapon as "I can deal this status effect" (and possibly an amount/intensity or other configuration?)
- Marking a recipient as "I can receive / react to this status effect" (and possibly tracking a resistance or vulnerability amount?)
- Processing the effects of the status effect on an afflicted recipient (eg. dealing damage periodically when poisoned / on fire)

These seem to me to be sufficiently distinct functions that they might not need to coexist in the same component.

I'd be inclined to introduce a StatusEffectType to express the shared "status effect identity" concept we need in all three roles.

- this could be an enumeration if you have a controlled list of status effects that should only grow occasionally in development / in major game updates.
- or, if you need to add custom status effects frequently, this could be a type of ScriptableObject, so you can create new status effects as data Assets frequently. This can hold a reference to the type or prefab of a component to apply the status effect when needed.

Now your weapon can contain a list of StatusEffectTypes that it can deal (possibly paired with intensity or other flavour attributes), and your recipients can contain a list of StatusEffectTypes they can receive (possibly paired with resistance/vulnerability attributes, or dormant components to act on those status effects)

Once you identify a match between a status effect a weapon deals and a struck recipient receives, you look up the appropriate behaviour component to activate / instantiate on the recipient.

If the component isn't already on the recipient or identified inside the StatusEffectType, you can also include a StatusEffectType on your status effect component prefabs, and search the list of those prefabs for one with a matching StatusEffectType.

This lets us get rid of the concept of an "inert" status effect component — the only ones we need are the ones actually inflicting effects on a recipient. This seems cleaner to my style of coding, and removes overhead of instantiating/storing/messaging script instances where we're not actually using their script behaviours.

---

If you'd prefer to keep these inert instances, then it sounds like you want `StatusEffectController.ActivateEffect` to activate the matching script of the same type on its own GameObject, rather than the one it got passed from the weapon's list. We can do that like so:

```
public void ActivateEffect(IStatusEffect effect) {
     var type = effect.GetType();

     if(activeEffects.Find((e) => { return e.GetType() == type;}) != null) {
         // Already active. Refresh it? Early-out?
     }

     // Look for a matching component on our own object.
     var match = gameObject.GetComponent(type);

     if(match == null) {
         // Dynamically add the component if it's missing?
         // match = AddComponent(type);
     }

     activeEffects.Add (match);

     // Activate component...
     // etc
}
```

Comment: They are not in the same component. A weapon doesn't check if it can deal a status effect, it just gives its projectiles the list of status effects it deals.

The recipient is the StatusEffectController, which just manages the storage,activation and deactivation of the effects. The effects themselves deal the damage to the actors.

The actor stores resistances in a separate "UnitStatus" script which only handles the health,energy,etc of the actor.

The last one you mentioned is dealt by the "StatusEffect" script itself.

Comment: I realized you mentioned the IStatusEffect interface. I used that because I didn't know another reliable way to access the contents of each differently named status effect script.

To answer your question, I do not wish to implement any checkers. I just want a StatusEffectController to activate any StatusEffects it receives and a gun to send status effects that it detects on its gameObject.

Comment: So, the components implementing IStatusEffect perform the third function, processing the effects on the recipient. But then the WeaponMaster gets the list of effects it can deal by searching for IStatusEffect components on itself. So in this case, those IStatusEffect components on the weapon aren't serving that same function (they're not afflicting the weapon), they're serving the first function, identifying the status effects the weapon deals. That's the mixed role that looks strange to me. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Only "StatusEffectBaseClass" implements "IStatusEffect", and yes, it processes the effects and sends any relevant outputs to the "UnitStatus" via the "StatusEffectController" which would sit right beside the "UnitStatus" if both were present.

The Status effects can only be activated by the "StatusEffectController", they are inert in other places.

You're pretty much correct.

Comment: I've updated the answer above to include a way to search for/spawn a matching component rather than activate the one on the weapon. I'd still advise against this route due to the overhead of the inert components described above, but this shouldn't be a show stopper if you find it to be a more convenient way to work. One other aside: it's a bit unusual to have a group of scripts share both a common base class and a common interface — usually one or the other will give the interchangeability you need. So we typically pick subclassing if inherited functionality is desired, or an interface if not.

Comment: `These seem to me to be sufficiently distinct functions that they might not need to coexist in the same component.` I would strengthen this statement to *should not*, not just *might not*.

Comment: Thanks for the info @DMGregory . I have managed to get the system working but I have one issue with the current method and one other question. I have edited the OP with the relevant details.

Comment: Each of these issues is distinct enough from your original problem that I'd recommend posting them as two new questions. One about avoiding conflicts between iterating a collection and adding items (be sure to include information about the flow & order of events that leads to the conflict), and one about cloning a component's values. I'll reiterate though that this gets *a lot* simpler if you just use a type object instead of using components for multiple distinct roles.